# php-html chinese language characters

Tags: php, html, character, symbols

I have a html screen, which contain Chinese Characters:

```
  <td class="bck_form_big" title="<?php print $orig_translator_title[PACKING_ERRORS]; ?>">&nbsp;<?php print $translator_title[PACKING_ERRORS]; ?></td>
                                <td class="bck_form_big">&nbsp;<input class="textstyle" size="35"  id="fault_1" name="fault_1" value="Case Contents / 码数对照" ></td>
                                <td class="bck_form_big">&nbsp;
                                    <input type="text" class="textstyle" size="5"  id="classification_1_CR" name="classification_1_CR" value="" onChange="calc_faults('<?php print $linha_config->layout_format; ?>');"/>&nbsp;<?php print $translator_title[FLDCR]; ?>&nbsp;
                                    <input type="text" class="textstyle" size="5"  id="classification_1_MJ" name="classification_1_MJ" value="" onChange="calc_faults('<?php print $linha_config->layout_format; ?>');"/>&nbsp;<?php print $translator_title[FLDMJ]; ?>&nbsp;
                                    <input type="text" class="textstyle" size="5"  id="classification_1_MN" name="classification_1_MN" value="" onChange="calc_faults('<?php print $linha_config->layout_format; ?>');"/>&nbsp;<?php print $translator_title[FLDMN]; ?>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td class="bck_form_big">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="textstyle" size="10"  id="cap_1" name="cap_1" value="" onBlur="faults_code_description(this);"></td>
```

As you can see, I have chinese characters to show up on screen.
First when I open the characters shows ok, but later when I refresh the page they become symbols.

As you can see in the pic:

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQo4M.jpg)

[when I open the page for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbeki.jpg)

[after refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc3FP.jpg)

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta charset="utf-8">`  or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` inside your `<head>` section.

Comment: I had add it before, and the issue is the same